# What automation approach is should I use to create and maintain many similar POCOs and DTOs?

Tags: c#, xamarin, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017, azure-table-storage

I need to maintain several similar files, with similar contents, but with slight differences for each purpose, such as the

- View (ASP.net, Xamarin.Forms, etc)
- ViewModel (Per field validation)
- Entity Framework Code first classes
- NoSQL classes iOS CloudKit, Azure table

Some of those require special implementations (INotifyPropertyChanged, Rx), or others require to be inherited from an abstract class.

**Question**

- Does any DTO automation (or schema description language) exist that allows for centralized management / property propagation of several similar files?

Perhaps I can extend visual studio to run a script in the background that will maintain the files, and alert me to any inconsistencies

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework already uses T4 templating for this purpose, and there's nothing preventing you from extending that mechanism to generate multiple copies of each class, each tailored to a specific purpose. You'd probably want to configure some rules and overrides for each type of code generation and perhaps for each entity type, but since it's just code you can basically do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your "groups" of classes configuration using JSON, XML or anything else.
Then you can use T4 templates to read this configuration and produce several similar classes for each group.

This will occur at save and\or build.